# How do I make my character movement less "buggy"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Whenever I'm running against a wall, like if there is a wall to my left and I hold 'a' against the wall it kinda spazes out. It looks like the character is going in and out of the wall. Hopefully that made sense and you know what I'm talking about. So my question is how could I fix this so that when I am actively running into a wall it doesnt do that and instead the character is just there against the wall and appearing to move at all.

code for the movement:

```
void Update()
{
var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < .001f)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the transform.position literally teleports the player, so it sometimes teleports them into the wall then they get pushed back.
To prevent that i suggest using the rigidbody's movePosition function. This takes into account physics while moving, so it interacts with the other objects that are there.

To change your current code to that it would be something like this:

```
    void Update()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //This moves the GameObject to the currentPosition + The move direction. Which means to move it in the direction that you intended to move in.
        _rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < .001f)
        {
        _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

However i suggest splitting it into this:

```
float movement = 0f; //Setting a default value.

void Update()
{
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //Getting movement input from player

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Mathf.Abs(_rigidbody.velocity.y) < .001f)
    {
        _rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{ //Moving in Physics update
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
}
```

Because Update checks every frame, so its good for checking input, however you should apply physics in FixedUpdate(), because that is applied whenever there is a physics update (Or physics frame). (For even more smoothness!)